# Mapping through Contentful nested array is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, array.prototype.map

I've successfully managed to bring the data back from Contentful but I can't seem to map further into the array. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I'm getting the following error: **field.fields.map is not a function**

```js
export default function Header({ links }) {
  console.log(links);
  return (
      <div className='header-links'>
        <ul className='flex text-white uppercase tracking-widest font-medium'>
          {links.map((link) => (
            <div key={link.title}>
              {link.links.map((field) => {
                <div>
                  {field.fields.map((singleLink) => (
                    <p>{singleLink.title}</p>
                  ))}
                </div>;
              })}
            </div>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
  );
}
```

```
[
  {
    "title": "Header",
    "logo": {},
    "links": [
      {
        "fields": {
          "title": "Home",
          "slug": "/"
        }
      },
      {
        "fields": {
          "title": "Food",
          "slug": "/Food"
        }
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: In your case fields is object not array hence the error. You can do field.fields.keys().map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it in this way. When you are inside the `field`, they are already object so you can not map like array anymore

```html
export default function Header({ links }) {
  console.log(links);
  return (
      <div className='header-links'>
        <ul className='flex text-white uppercase tracking-widest font-medium'>
          {links.map((link) => (
            <div key={link.title}>
              {link?.links?.map((field) => (
                <div>
                <p>{field?.fields?.title}</p>
                </div>
              )
            )}
            </div>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. But could you explain what ? is doing....

Comment: Basically in first map it enters inside the big object then in this object there is an array called 'link' and it maps again this array to reach the objects of the array. Inside the <p> tags I just get the title of this objects with field?.fields?.title @TheInteractiveDOM